# mySQL Load Data - Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, sqlalchemy

I've looked at many similar questions on this topic.. But none appear to apply.
Here are the details:

I have a table with 8 columns.

```
create table test (
node_name varchar(200),
parent  varchar(200),
actv int(11),
fid int(11),
cb varchar(100),
co datetime,
ub varchar(100),
uo datetime
);
```

There is a trigger on the table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_test
BEFORE INSERT ON test
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.co = now(), NEW.uo = now(), NEW.cb = user(), NEW.ub = user()
```

I have a csv file to load into this table. Its got just 2 columns in it.
First few rows:

```
node_name,parent
West,
East,
BBB: someone,West
Quebec,East
Ontario,East
Manitoba,West
British Columbia,West
Atlantic,East
Alberta,West
```

I have this all set up in a mySQL 5.6 environment. Using python and SQLAlchemy, i run the load of the file without issue..  It LOADS ALL RECORDS with empty strings for the second field in the first 2 records. All as expected.

I have a mysql 8 environment, and run the exact same routine. All the same statements, etc. It fails with the 'Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns' error.

The connection is made using this:

```
engine = create_engine(
connection_string,
pool_size=6, max_overflow=10, encoding='latin1', isolation_level='AUTOCOMMIT',
connect_args={"local_infile": 1}
)
db_connection = engine.connect()
```

The Command I place in the sql variable is:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'test.csv' 
INTO TABLE test 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  ENCLOSED BY '\"' IGNORE 1 LINES SET fid = 526, actv = 1;
```

And execute it with:

```
    db_connection.execute(sql)
```

So.. I basically **load** the first two columns from the file.. I **set** the next 2 columns in the load statement, and the final 4 others are handled by the **trigger**.

**I repeat - this is working fine in the mysql 5 environment, but not the mysql 8.**

I checked mysql character set variables in both db environments, and they are equivalent (just in case the default character set change between 5.6 and 8 had an impact).

I will say that the mySQL 5 db is running on ubuntu 18.04.5 while mySQL 8 is running on ubuntu 20.02.2 - could there be something there??

I have tried all sorts of fiddling with the LOAD DATA statement.. I tried filling in data for the first two records in the file in case that was it.. I tried using different line terminators in the LOAD statement..  I'm at a loss for the next thing to look into..
Thanks for any pointers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL will assume that each row in your CSV maps to a column in the table, unless you tell it otherwise.

Give the query a column list:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'test.csv' 
INTO TABLE test 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  
ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(node_name, parent)
SET fid = 526, actv = 1;
```

Comment: i'll give this a try tomorrow.. but is it something that changed between v5 and v8?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware, but the operation of LOAD DATA INFILE is modified by the setting of the `sql_mode` system variable. That might differ between different installations of MySQL. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-column-assignments for all the gory details.

Comment: Ah.. that might be it then.. I know sql_mode defaults are definitely different.. I’ll find out which one is specifically causing this..

Comment: yeah, after reading through the doc, i added the IGNORE keyword to use unrestrictive mode.. and it just gives warnings but loads the data. It still seems like a bug somewhere, since there IS data for every column in the end (as per the TRIGGERs).. but it gives me a warning for every single row it inserts, complaining there isn't data for all columns. Maybe i'll log it for them to look into

Comment: by the way.. i'm trying to avoid the column listing as this stuff is all generated dynamically and my lazy side doesn't want to have to figure out the columns.. SO i may just go with the ignore (hoping that i don't miss out on real errors)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Tangentially Perpendicular's answer, there are other options:

1. add the IGNORE keyword as per:
   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#ignore-effect-on-execution
   it should come just before the ' INTO' in the LOAD DATA statement as per https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html.
2. or, altering the sql_mode to be less strict will work also.

Due to the strict sql_mode, LOAD DATA isn't smart enough to realize that TRIGGERS are handling a couple columns..  Would be nice if they enhanced it to be that smart.. but alas.